# Please change "suggested" to "approved" in Revisions list for an approved suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, revisions-list

I just noticed something confusing which can be easily improved.

See this screenshot from a [revisions list](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/posts/14229/revisions):

> [image]

From this it looks like I suggested the edit 49 minutes ago. But looking in the [suggested edit](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/3622) itself, we can see it was actually suggested/proposed 19 hours ago:

> [image]

So, can the "suggested x y ago" be changed to "approved x y ago" to prevent confusion?

On big sites like Stack Overflow (and probably all trilogy sites) it's not relevant as edits are approved within minutes, but on smaller sites it might take days for suggested edit to be approved.

Comment: Almost was going to ask to fix it.

Comment: And btw why display approved? It is a bit confusing too.  Just "edited".

Comment: @nicael I think there is value in telling it was a suggested edit rather than a "full" edit.

Comment: Full edit doesn't have a link. But suggested does.

Comment: @nicael good point, but still having one edit clickable and one not clickable will be confusing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting from the next build, instead of "suggested", the link text in the revision list will be "edit approved", if the revision originated from a suggested edit.

rev 2014.7.29.1731, meta rev 2014.7.29.2401